# SQL queries for recurring events from this schema from vertabelo

Tags: sql, sql-server, events, recurring

I'm looking for a solution to implement a recurring events. I found this article and I really like the schema they propose for the DB. My issue is that they don't provide any queries to get the events.

https://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/again-and-again-managing-recurring-events-in-a-data-model

For example, I would like to be able to see all the events for a month but I'm kind of lost. I don't know what query could give me that (there is a lot of parameters like the recurring type, the separation count...). I also would like to see all the events for a selected date.

If someone already worked with this schema or something similar, could you give me any advice?

Thanks for your help.

I forgot to say that I'm working with SQL server.

Comment: Link throws a 404 error. I can't read it

Comment: @PausePause, sorry for that, the link is https://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/again-and-again-managing-recurring-events-in-a-data-model